# Class with x amount of additional objects

Tags: c#, class, object

Lets say I have an class called Person with a constructor

```
public class Person
{
     public string Name { get; set;}
     public string Height { get; set; }
     public string WhatEverElse { get; set; }

     public string Person(string Name, string Height, string WhatEverElse)
     {
          this.Name = Name;
          .......
     }
}
```

Now lets say I want to also include all the pets a person might have.

```
List<Person> persons = new List<Person>();

persons.Add(new Person("Larry", "5'9", "Whatever"));

foreach(Datarow row in OwnedPets)
{
     //push the pet info to the person here
}
```

Is there a way I can add x amount of pets and pet information to the Person Object? That way I can return Larry with all 2 of his pets or Jerry with all 6 of his pets?
Or can I combine two classes an return a list with both?

Comment: Just add a property named `Pets` of type `List<Pet>` or `List<string>` or whatever.  Then in your loop you would do `person.Pets.Add(pet);`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How about a List?

```
public class Person
{
     public string Name { get; set;}
     public string Height { get; set; }
     public string WhatEverElse { get; set; }
     public List<Pet> Pets { get; set; }
     public string Person(string Name, string Height, string WhatEverElse)
     {
          Pets = new List<Pet>();
     }
}

public class Pet
{
     public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

You can then add any amount of Pets by assigning new Pets

```
// For your own sake keep a clear naming convention - just my two bucks
List<Person> persons = new List<Person>();
Person person = new Person("Larry", "5'9", "Whatever");
persons.Add(person);

foreach(Datarow row in OwnedPets)
{
     Pet newPet = new Pet();
     person.Pets.Add(newPet);
}
```

Comment: Lol, both answers came at the same time. Mine uses a class for pets.

Comment: but take care his naming is confusing! `person` is the list not the person itself o.O

Comment: I updated the sample... Mentioning the importance of naming convention ;-)

Comment: I updated my question for better naming conventions. I went this route and making a separate class for my information. Many thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Add a Pets list to your person

```
public class Person
{
     public string Name { get; set;}
     public string Height { get; set; }
     public string WhatEverElse { get; set; }
     public List<string> Perts = new List<strings>();

     public string Person(string Name, string Height, string WhatEverElse)
     {
          this.Name = Name;
          .......
     }
}
```

now you can add as many pets as you like

```
Person per = new Person("Larry", "5'9", "Whatever");
per.Pets.Add("Tom");
per.Pets.Add("Jerry");
person.Add(per);
```

P.S. your list of type `Person` should not be named "person" that's super confusing. Call it "persons" or something like that

Comment: I used a mix of your answer and the other answer. I used a class of Pet but then added the list object to my Person like you did above. Thanks!